# Using Ubuntu 22.04 as DNS Server with bind9

Tags: networking, server, dns, firewall, ufw

I want to use a simple ubuntu 22.04 server as a DNS Server for my pc.

I created a new server, with a static ip address, that i will type in to my dns in windows.
My problem is, when i try

`nslookup google.de @123.123.123.12`

Than i get the error, `nslookup: couldn't get address for '@123.123.123.12': not found`.

So i cannot use my server ip as dns or just to check nslookup from external device.
When i am on the server console and just doing `nslookup google.de` without @ to my server, than it works fine with the DNS. But when i will use my server static ip address, i cannot just ping over it.

Any ideas, what the problem is here?
I already tried `ufw allow 53/udp` and `ufw allow 53/tcp`
The `ufw status` is active and i also see the rules added there.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Problem!

I forgot to add `allow-query { any; };` to my bind9 named options